# Django: How to convert HTML date from request to Python string

Tags: python, mysql, django

I having trouble converting Date from HTML to Python String to use it in query

I want to send query to MySQL with Date argument.

```
roomList=Room.objects.raw(
             "select room.id "
 +"from room join client_room on room.id=client_room.room_id "
 +"where client_room.date_in>'"+request.GET.get("date_out")+ ..."#argument-date_out
```

I recieve Date from HTML

```
            <p>
                <label>Enter first date</label><br>
                <input type="date" name="date_in" value="{{date1}}"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Enter second date</label><br>
                <input type="date" name="date_out" value="{{date2}}"/>
            </p>
```

While printing Date alone it prints correctly

```
print(request.GET.get("date_in"))
2021-04-01#Terminal
```

But if trying to assign and/or concatenate it returns NoneType

```
date=request.GET.get("date_in")
print("Date is " + date)
can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str #HTML Response
```

Comment: Try using the datetime module https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

Comment: The way you are making queries you are **vulnerable to SQL Injection**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by using Django DateTimeField class.

```
date=models.DateTimeField()
date=request.GET.get("date_in")
print("Date is " + str(date))
Date is 2021-04-09#Terminal
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `strftime`:

```py
from datetime import datetime
print("Date is " + datetime.strftime(date))
```

Comment: I've tried already. It doesn't work for 'NoneType' objects

`descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'NoneType' object`

Comment: @valentine then your `date` is `None` for some reason, I do not know why.